# Can I rewrite this SQL query to avoid the "The ORDER BY clause is invalid "

Tags: sql, sql-server, jdbc

My query originally was this:

```
select a.ID, a.TransactionID, b.Result 
from MyDB.Result a inner join MyDB.ResultData b on a.ID=b.ID 
where a.ID < 100000 and a.CreatedOn > '2020-01-01' 
order by a.ID
```

But I got the error in Elasticsearch JDBC input

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

To get around it I refactored it to this:

```
select TOP 500 a.ID, a.TransactionID, b.Result 
from MyDB.Result a inner join MyDB.ResultData b on a.ID=b.ID 
where a.ID < 100000 and a.CreatedOn > '2020-01-01' 
order by a.ID
```

Is there any way I can rewrite it so as not to have to ask for TOP 500 and instead let the JDBC plugin use its inbuilt settings?

**EDIT:**
This is a section from the logs. This does look to be running as a part of a bigger query.

```
(1.251403s) SELECT TOP (1) count(*) AS [COUNT] FROM (select TOP 500 a.ID, a.TransactionID, b.Result from MyDB.Result a inner join MyDB.ResultData b on a.ID=b.ResultID where a.ID < 100000 and a.CreatedOn > '2020-01-01' order by a.ID) AS [T1]
(8.845048s) SELECT * FROM (select TOP 500 a.ID, a.TransactionID, b.Result from MyDB.Result a inner join MyDB.ResultData b on a.ID=b.ResultID where a.ID < 100000 and a.CreatedOn > '2020-01-01' order by a.ID) AS [T1] ORDER BY 1 OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 500 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with the orignal query. What else is this embedded in? It must be part if a larger query, and if so the order by must be in the outer query. And BTW while TOP will stop the error, it is actually saying "return the first 500 rows when ordered by ID", if its in a subquery etc it won't sort the results.

Comment: Where do you have this SQL statement. Please put the whole code, how you are calling in JDBC also

Comment: As per error he ORDER BY clause is invalid in views....,that is not your original error.you can write ORDER BY  in final query.

Comment: @VenkataramanR This is the statement I provide to the Logstash input plugin to get data. Its not as such a part of code. Just part of script.

Comment: @TomC I added some parts from the logs. Had to redact some stuff but I think it should be fine.

Comment: So you can clearly see that your query is embedded inside two other queries - the count, followed by the select. Is this from your code? If not its a pretty poorly written library because it runs each query twice. See if you can turn off whatever it is doing. Or do your sorting in code after you get the results.

Answer (score 0):

When you use subquery with TOP Clause as FROM , it requires ORDER BY.

> #### Subquery rules
>
> ORDER BY can only be specified when TOP is also specified.

[Read about all subquery rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-ver15#rules)

What you can do is, you can move the ORDER BY outside the FROM clause. I understand that you want all the rows, instead of only 500 rows.

```
(1.251403s) SELECT TOP (1) count(*) AS [COUNT] FROM (select a.ID,  
a.TransactionID, b.Result from MyDB.Result a inner join MyDB.ResultData b 
on a.ID=b.ResultID where a.ID < 100000 and a.CreatedOn > '2020-01-01') AS [T1]
order by ID 

(8.845048s) SELECT * FROM (select a.ID, a.TransactionID, b.Result from MyDB.Result a    
inner join MyDB.ResultData b on a.ID=b.ResultID where a.ID < 100000    
and a.CreatedOn > '2020-01-01' order by a.ID) AS [T1] ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: I dont think the OP can do this - they appear to be only passing the embedded query. And some other part of the library is embedding it as a subquery.

Comment: @TomC, OP has mentioned that to get around, I refactored the query. That is the reason, I mentioned it